# Sound not playing on Windows XP - SoundEffect or Song: Monogame

Tags: xna, windows, monogame

*Solution:*** I have a RealTek ALC888. I solved this (OpenAL) by disabling hardware acceleration on my sound (Control Panel > Sound > Advanced, disable acceleration).

I'm trying to integrate sound into my Monogame game. I don't have the content pipeline hack -- just straight Monogame (Beta 3) at this point.

(I tried adding the content pipeline, but ran into some issues.)

I added a .wav file to my `/Content` directory, and I can create and instantiate both `SoundEffect` and `Song` classes. However, both show durations of `00:00:00` (on a ten-second long file), and neither plays.

I can call `LoadContent` without any issue. But when I call `Play`, nothing plays.

I've tried a couple of different sounds, and different formats (MP3 and WAV) to rule that out. Only WAV seems to even load without crashing out, but it doesn't play.

**This issue only occurs on Windows XP.** I tested it on a Windows 7 laptop, and the sound plays fine.

**Edit:** I [opened a MonoGame issue](http://monogame.codeplex.com/workitem/7228) to track this, and it includes several more details.

Comment: Why don't you use plain XNA for the Windows builds of your game?

Comment: @r2d2rigo I don't trust that MS will support XNA moving forward. Monogame lets me run on Windows 8, plus I can include Android and iPhone once I buy the licenses.

Comment: If the problem is fixed in 3.0... why not use 3.0?

Comment: @JariKomppa sorry, I forgot to delete that. It's *not* fixed in 3.0, a different issue is.

Comment: Was MonoGame compiled in Windows XP? Or are you just running what was compiled in Windows 7 in XP? If you haven't tried it already, compile MonoGame itself in Windows XP.

Comment: I have compiled MonoGame myself @ViteFalcon. I opened an issue for this: http://monogame.codeplex.com/workitem/7228

Comment: Have you checked out the audio configuration? There is a discussion here worth checking out: http://www.frictionalgames.com/forum/thread-4248.html

One interesting suggestion is as at the bottom of the first page: Check the Hardware Acceleration slider in Control Panel->Sounds and Audio Devices->(Speaker Settings)Advanced...->Performance tab and make sure it is set to "Full".

Comment: @RyanMaloney it is already set to full, thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as though [I am not the only one](http://www.facepuncher.com/blogs/10parameters/?p=32) with problems getting MonoGame to run sounds on XP:

> A very simple alternative is using SoundEffect SoundEffectInstance classes. It is incredibly easy to modify your Windows XACT code to use SoundEffect SoundEffectInstance, HOWEVER, **I personally have had problems getting SoundEffect/SoundEffectInstance to work correctly under Windows XP** where as XACT works just fine. So I decided to leave XACT on my Windows game and just use SoundEffect/SoundEffectInstance on Mac.

(Emphasis mine.) Based on this, I can safely assume that MonoGame/XP is broken for audio. Unfortunately, [Steam's hardware survey](http://store.steampowered.com/hwsurvey) frequently cites around 10% of their user-base uses XP. So it's vital to support it.

To make this work, I has a sad. I already have my game/framework code both split by platform (Windows and Android). I added NAudio to the Windows side, along with [this lovely OGG player for NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/discussions/235249).

To get my framework code to be uniform, I:

- Created an interface on top of XNA's `SoundEffect` class
- Created my own `NAudioSoundEffect` and `XnaSoundEffect` classes (former wraps NAudio, the latter wraps the XNA `SoundEffect` class)
- Use Ninject to inject a factory by platform. It returns the correct sound effect class (`XnaSoundEffect` on all platforms except windows, which gets `NAudioSoundEffect`)

The solution allowed me to have a single `AudioComponent` class with an `ISoundEffect` instance, internally, which is platform-specific. And it works.

Comment: Have you considered sending a pull request to the MonoGame team?

Comment: @VaughanHilts why would they be interested in my change? I put everything (eg. `SpriteBatch`, `Texture2D`) behind interfaces, wrote filler code, and did a bunch of other "major" changes they might not approve of.