# Portable sound and music for XNA / MonoGame?

Tags: xna, xna-4.0, sound, audio, monogame

What is the best (recommended) way to integrate audio (both sound effect and music) in a game project (using C#/XNA) targeting multiple desktop platforms (W7, W8 Metro, Linux, OSX, ...) via MonoGame. XACT was the usual way in XNA but it is deprecated in W8 and also cannot be used with MonoGame, I am looking for an alternaive. Is there one?

Answer (score 1):

The "usual" way is to use the `SoundEffect` class. This will work on multiple platforms out of the box; it's done "the XNA way," so if you've used XNA, you should be familiar with how this works.

The only issue I found so far (tested on XP, Win7, and Android emulator) is that **sound doesn't work on XP.** I posted my long, painful saga (and solution) in [this question and answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/44786/sound-not-playing-on-windows-xp-soundeffect-or-song-monogame/48577#48577). (TLDR: OpenAL doesn't work on XP, so use NAudio for Windows instead.)

Comment: Couldn't you use the Microsoft XNA implementation on XP?

Comment: @AndrewRussell why would I want my game referencing both MonoGame and Microsoft XNA? I'd rather just select a subset of it -- or even a subset of the NAudio library.